# How to: Linux script running in windows 10

Tags: linux, bash, script

I am new to linux. and I like to know that if I create a bash script and make it executable with ".sh" extension. I like to know how or can I make this executable in windows?

Comment: If the only thing you need from unix subsystem(without other useful utilities ) is a shell scripting you can use standalone [bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) interpreter  for windows systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10, it cannot run bash scripts. WSL comes with the 64-bit editions of Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

The executable permission is an object of ext4 file system which Windows 10 does not recognize. But there is the equivalent "Read and execute" permission in Windows NTFS. Anyway, scripts do not need "execute" permission to run because they are treated as data files.

Comment: this should be the answer imo

Answer (score 0):

There are [bash for windows](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) available which you need to install on your system in order to run shell files but there are alternative to run shell files such as

[**Cygwin**](https://www.cygwin.com/)

> Cygwin is free software that provides a Unix-like environment and
>   software tool set to users of any modern x86 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions of MS-Windows (XP with SP3/Server 20xx/Vista/7/8) and (using
>   older versions of Cygwin) some obsolete versions (95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP
>   without SP3) as well.

[**Uwin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWIN)

> Uwin is an X/Open library for the Windows 32-bit application
>   programming interface (API), called Win32. UWIN contains:
>
> - Libraries that emulate a Unix environment by implementing the Unix API
> - Include files and development tools such as cc(1), yacc(1), lex(1), and make(1).
> - ksh(1) (the Korn Shell) and over 250 utilities such as ls(1), sed(1), cp(1), stty(1), etc.

Comment: Using Cygwin, you compile code. I dont have a code I have an exe file

Comment: @alex how did you go from a shell script to an .exe?

Comment: I mean .sh file

Comment: @Alex you can run shell file in cygwin.

Comment: can I run c program written in linux in windows. is c library is same across  OSs?

Comment: @Alex when you will install cygwin you have to check that you are installing all the dependencies required to run c program on cygwin otherwise it will not run if you missed some program on installation you can use [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) rep.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar why is that is c is different for windows and linux?

Comment: @Alex no you are misunderstanding, cygwin is overall different package it will not use your windows c package you have to install it exclusive for cygwin at the time of installation.